# Get confused of some rails concepts, needs some explanations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I got confused of some Rails' concepts like: gemset, rubygems, bundler . I have following three questions:

**1.** After I installed the RVM tool, what are the correct steps to setup the development enviroment for creating a rails project (say rails v2.3 project)

**2.** What is the difference between "`gem install XXX`" and "`bundle install`"? Can I understand it in the way that "`bundle install`" install all gems needed in the app at once while "`gem install XXX`" only install the specified "`XXX`" gem ?  Are there any other difference? Why not use bundler to install specific rails then?

**3.** If I want to use rails v3.0 for project_one, and use rails v2.3 for project_two. How to create the two projects with the specific rails versions? How about different ruby versions for different projects? Do I only need to specify the needed version in **Gemfile** or install the needed version under the project path?

Comment: I would have liked to have three different questions.

Comment: @Leem These are rvm concepts, not Rails.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

RVM allows you to create different gemsets alongside different ruby versions.

You can install different versions of ruby with `rvm install`.

`rvm install 1.8.7`

`rvm install 1.9.2`

`rvm list known` will tell you the available ruby implementations you can install.

Say, you have two projects: project_one and project_two, and both of them have different gem dependencies. So you'll want to create two empty gemsets with, say, Ruby 1.9.2.

```
rvm gemset create 1.9.2@project_one
rvm gemset create 1.9.2@project_two
```

To use project_two's gemset, you can use `rvm use` to select the gemset.

```
rvm use 1.9.2@project_two
```

You can also add the above command into a file called `.rvmrc` in the root path of your rails application, which rvm will load automatically whenever you cd into the app's root directory.

If you want to use Rails 2.3.8 for project_one,

```
rvm use 1.9.2@project_one
gem install rails -v 2.3.8
```

and Rails 3.1.0 for project_two,

```
rvm use 1.9.2@project_two
gem install rails -v 3.1.0
```

The difference between `gem install` and `bundle install` is that `gem install` installs only the specified gem into your gemset, while `bundle install` installs all the gems located in your app's `Gemfile`.

Comment: Hi, what does the "1.9.2" indicates in the command "rvm gemset create 1.9.2@project_one"

Comment: @Leem It refers to the ruby version.

Comment: should the command "rvm use 1.9.2@project_two" be executed under project_two path? or outside?

Comment: can I specify different ruby version for different project by change the version number in "rvm gemset create RUBY-VERSION@project_name"?

Comment: @Leem it can be executed anywhere, and will remain the same until you switch it or a `.rvmrc` is loaded.

Comment: @Leem Yes you can specify different ruby versions for different project. Make sure that version is installed first, though.

Answer (score 2):

1) If you have a rvm setup I propose add in in your app file **.rvmrc**
and in that file:

```
rvm --create ree-1.8.7-2011.03@myappname
```

This will alway use specify version of ruby (in that case 'ree-1.8.7-2011.03') and all gems will be installed in rvm gemset named: myappname. This file will always make sure every time you go to that folder from bash_console it will point rvm to correct environment.

2) If you have rvm setup then:

**gem install XXX** creates gem in specify rvm gemset or if not global rvm gemset

**sudo gem install XXX** will add gems to you Global gems

Like you said, you should always use Bundle install, and group gems for development,test, production.

3) This can achieve like I said in point 1) just create this file in your app